# Running a QT Software on Android

Tags: android, linux, qt, embedded

I have a problem with a `Device Driver` for a `camera` that only runs on Android. 
I have a software that is written in `QT` and developed in `Ubuntu`. Is it possible to run that software alone on Android ?
Run it like a `gui` and everything ?

Comment: chick this mailing archive https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/VkK8xodG2rE

Answer (score 1):

Yes, preliminary support for Android and iOS is available in the Qt5.1. Full Android and iOS support will be in Qt5.2.

There is more information and download link for the Qt5.1 aplha in this digia blog post:
http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/04/08/qt-5-1-alpha-available/

When Qt5.1 and 5.2 are officially released you will be able to download them here:
http://qt-project.org/downloads